# Casting to Button is redundant - Why?

Tags: android, button, casting, findviewbyid

I've just came across this interesting message from the compiler and I do not know why is it happening. Here is the case

Example 1.

```
Button test = (Button) findViewById(R.id.someButtonId);
test.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Example 2.

```
findViewById(R.id.someButtonId).setOnClickListener(this);
```

In the first example, I need to cast an object returned by `findViewById` to `Button`. In the second example, I do not have to cast returned object because I did not use another `Button` class object. If I try to cast it via

```
((Button)findViewById(R.id.someButtonId)).setOnClickListener(this);
```

I will get the warning `Casting findViewById(R.id.someButtonId) to Button is redundant`.

Why is this happening? I am not trying to remove cast warning. I want to **know the logic behind this** and why casting is not needed if I do not try to initialize another object with the object returned by `findViewById`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3502690/remove-redundant-casts-in-java

Comment: @Samir I know how to remove it :). I don't need that. I am asking **why** casting is not needed.

Comment: :( i am not getting the warning

Comment: @rajesh.adhi Use IntelliJ IDEA and you will. The best tool! ;)

Comment: :O i am using Eclipse, thanks anyway

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The reason why you get this is because `findViewById` returns `View` and this class already defines the method `setOnClickListener`. This means that even without doing the cast you can set the listener. Thus your cast is redundant.

Comment: To ask here as well: is it safe using it like in examp2?

Comment: Why do you think it would not be safe?

Comment: @VladimirVolodin I do not like working with parent objects like `View`. That's why I'm more comfortable when I work with explicit objects like in examp1. Am I over-concerned or wrongly-concerned?

Comment: You are wrongly concerned in this case. It is perfectly fine to work with parent objects. I am totally sure you do not feel like doing something bad if you access a method of interface right. And still it is just the same case as accessing a method of parent class. After all it is always the case that you actually call the method of  `Button`, just the calling "string" is different.

Comment: @sandalone, you should familiarize yourself more with the programming concept of polymorphism - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/polymorphism.html

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: im learning Android in 2019, which seems that now even using `example 1`, you dont need to cast to `Button` object anymore?

Comment: @Isaac Confirmed. Things change to the better :) Warm welcome to us Android devs :)

Answer (score 2):

The **findViewById()** always returns View which is parent of all Views such as ImageView, Button...

The **setOnClickListener** is a method of View class. So you can catch the click events simply without casting it to Button. I think so that only it says redundant.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for this is that in Example 1 you explicitly need to find a Button because you are assigning it to a Button variable.

The OnClickListener is for any type of View, so you do not need to cast it to a specific subclass of View to set an OnClickListener to it.

Comment: Absolutely. Whatever View is found in example 2, an OnClickListener can be set on it.

Comment: You will anyway know it's a button for sure, because you do not use the id someButtonId for any other Views, do you?

Answer (score 1):

It's happening because you don't need to cast `View` to `Button` in order to call `setOnClickListener` which is defined in `View`. It's enough to do `findViewById(R.id.someButtonId).setOnClickListener(this);`

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing setOnClickListener() is a method in the View rather than the Button, and so yep: the cast is redundant.